# Extract data from an array of product-items

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-structures, interface, reduce

I have the following dataArray

```
const dataArray = [
    {
        "identifier": "sku-01",
        "data": [
            {
                "productName": "Drink1",
                "productProperty": {
                    "productVolume": "110 ml"
                }
            },
            {
                "productName": "Drink2",
                "productProperty": {
                    "productVolume": "110 ml"
                }
            },
            {
                "productName": "Drink3",
                "productProperty": {
                    "productVolume": "110 ml"
                }
            },
            {
                "productName": "Drink4",
                "productProperty": {
                    "productVolume": "110 ml"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "identifier": "sku-02",
        "data": [
            {
                "productName": "Drink1",
                "productProperty": {
                    "productVolume": "120 ml"
                }
            },
            {
                "productName": "Drink2",
                "productProperty": {
                    "productVolume": "120 ml"
                }
            },
            {
                "productName": "Drink3",
                "productProperty": {
                    "productVolume": "120 ml"
                }
            },
            {
                "productName": "Drink4",
                "productProperty": {
                    "productVolume": "120 ml"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "identifier": "sku-03",
        "data": [
            {
                "productName": "Drink1",
                "productProperty": {
                    "productVolume": "130 ml"
                }
            },
            {
                "productName": "Drink2",
                "productProperty": {
                    "productVolume": "130 ml"
                }
            },
            {
                "productName": "Drink3",
                "productProperty": {
                    "productVolume": "130 ml"
                }
            },
            {
                "productName": "Drink4",
                "productProperty": {
                    "productVolume": "130 ml"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to convert it into something like:

```
   const result = [
  {
    drink1: [
      { identifier: 'sku-01', productVolume: '110 ml' },
      { identifier: 'sku-02', productVolume: '120 ml' },
      { identifier: 'sku-03', productVolume: '130 ml' },
    ],
  },
  {
    drink2: [
      { identifier: 'sku-01', productVolume: '110 ml' },
      { identifier: 'sku-02', productVolume: '120 ml' },
      { identifier: 'sku-03', productVolume: '130 ml' },
    ],
  },
  {
    drink3: [
      { identifier: 'sku-01', productVolume: '110 ml' },
      { identifier: 'sku-02', productVolume: '120 ml' },
      { identifier: 'sku-03', productVolume: '130 ml' },
    ],
  },
  {
    drink4: [
      { identifier: 'sku-01', productVolume: '110 ml' },
      { identifier: 'sku-02', productVolume: '120 ml' },
      { identifier: 'sku-03', productVolume: '130 ml' },
    ],
  },
];
```

I can already do this with a for loop and by re-creating objects inside the result, but that looks kinda ugly. Is there a clean way of doing it with ES6? How would I approach it? ProductName is dynamic, and there can be many products inside the data array.

Comment: There is nothing like a JSON array or JSON object. JS data-structures can be provided and transferred/interchanged as [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) strings (see [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)). Such strings can be converted back into objects by a parse process like `JSON.parse`. Thus `JSON` stands for both, a JavaScript namespace with methods and a syntax for serializing data-structures.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need an extra interface or type for the pure JavaScript solutions from other answers to work (or define one inline, which is less optimal).  But generally the solution is the same as the other people.

```
const dataArray = [
    {
    "identifier": "sku-01",
    "data": [
        {
            "productName": "Drink1",
            "productProperty": {
                "productVolume": "110 ml"
            }
        },
        {
            "productName": "Drink2",
            "productProperty": {
                "productVolume": "110 ml"
            }
        },
        {
            "productName": "Drink3",
            "productProperty": {
                "productVolume": "110 ml"
            }
        },
        {
            "productName": "Drink4",
            "productProperty": {
                "productVolume": "110 ml"
            }
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "identifier": "sku-02",
    "data": [
        {
            "productName": "Drink1",
            "productProperty": {
                "productVolume": "120 ml"
            }
        },
        {
            "productName": "Drink2",
            "productProperty": {
                "productVolume": "120 ml"
            }
        },
        {
            "productName": "Drink3",
            "productProperty": {
                "productVolume": "120 ml"
            }
        },
        {
            "productName": "Drink4",
            "productProperty": {
                "productVolume": "120 ml"
            }
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "identifier": "sku-03",
    "data": [
        {
            "productName": "Drink1",
            "productProperty": {
                "productVolume": "130 ml"
            }
        },
        {
            "productName": "Drink2",
            "productProperty": {
                "productVolume": "130 ml"
            }
        },
        {
            "productName": "Drink3",
            "productProperty": {
                "productVolume": "130 ml"
            }
        },
        {
            "productName": "Drink4",
            "productProperty": {
                "productVolume": "130 ml"
            }
        }
    ]
    }
]

interface ResultEntry {
    [key: string]: { identifier: string, productVolume: string }[]
}

const converted = dataArray.reduce((result, entry) => {
    const { identifier } = entry;
    entry.data.forEach(drink => {
      const { productName, productProperty: { productVolume } }= drink;
      const key = productName.toLowerCase();
      result[key] = result[key] || [];
      result[key].push({ identifier, productVolume });
      return result;
    });
    return result
}, {} as ResultEntry);

const result = Object.entries(converted).map(([key, val]) => ({ [key]: val }));
console.log(result);
```

You could also get a pure JavaScript solution, but you'd need to be a little more explicit and roundabout about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could group by `productName` and push new objects with `identifier` and `productVolume`.

```js
const
    data = [{ identifier: "sku-01", data: [{ productName: "Drink1", productProperty: { productVolume: "110 ml" } }, { productName: "Drink2", productProperty: { productVolume: "110 ml" } }, { productName: "Drink3", productProperty: { productVolume: "110 ml" } }, { productName: "Drink4", productProperty: { productVolume: "110 ml" } }] }, { identifier: "sku-02", data: [{ productName: "Drink1", productProperty: { productVolume: "120 ml" } }, { productName: "Drink2", productProperty: { productVolume: "120 ml" } }, { productName: "Drink3", productProperty: { productVolume: "120 ml" } }, { productName: "Drink4", productProperty: { productVolume: "120 ml" } }] }, { identifier: "sku-03", data: [{ productName: "Drink1", productProperty: { productVolume: "130 ml" } }, { productName: "Drink2", productProperty: { productVolume: "130 ml" } }, { productName: "Drink3", productProperty: { productVolume: "130 ml" } }, { productName: "Drink4", productProperty: { productVolume: "130 ml" } }] }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { identifier, data }) => {
        data.forEach(({ productName, productProperty: { productVolume } }) => {
            (r[productName] ??= []).push({ identifier, productVolume })
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Typescript doesn't like this. Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'. for the statement (r[productName] ??= [])

Comment: sorry, i have no idea of typescript.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```js
const dataArray = [
{"identifier": "sku-01",
    "data": [{"productName": "Drink1", "productProperty": { "productVolume": "110 ml" }},
             {"productName": "Drink2", "productProperty": { "productVolume": "110 ml" }},
             {"productName": "Drink3", "productProperty": { "productVolume": "110 ml" }},
             {"productName": "Drink4", "productProperty": { "productVolume": "110 ml" }}] },{"identifier": "sku-02",
    "data": [{"productName": "Drink1", "productProperty": { "productVolume": "120 ml" }},
             {"productName": "Drink2", "productProperty": { "productVolume": "120 ml" }},
             {"productName": "Drink3", "productProperty": { "productVolume": "120 ml" }},
             {"productName": "Drink4", "productProperty": { "productVolume": "120 ml" }}] },{"identifier": "sku-03",
    "data": [{"productName": "Drink1", "productProperty": { "productVolume": "130 ml" }},
             {"productName": "Drink2", "productProperty": { "productVolume": "130 ml" }},
             {"productName": "Drink3", "productProperty": { "productVolume": "130 ml" }},
             {"productName": "Drink4", "productProperty": { "productVolume": "130 ml" }}] }];

const res=Object.entries(dataArray.reduce((acc,s)=>{
  s.data.forEach(d=>{ 
    (acc[d.productName]=acc[d.productName]??[])
            .push({identifier:s.identifier,productVolume:d.productProperty.productVolume});
  })
  return acc
}, {})).map(([k,v])=>({[k]:v}));

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100% !important}
```

Comment: Typescript doesn't like it :( Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'. for this line (acc[d.productName]=acc[d.productName]??[])

Comment: I just tagged your question as typescript. You just wasted Nina's and my time trying to find a JavaScriot solution. Like Nina, I can't help you with typescript but maybe you can take our answers and develop them further?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited the tags now.